# How to write the julia version of Portfolio.optim of R

Tags: r, julia

I was studying how to compute an efficient portfolio from the given return series x in the mean-variance sense. In R the code is like this.

```
portfolio.optim(x, pm = mean(x), riskless = FALSE,
                shorts = FALSE, rf = 0.0, reslow = NULL, reshigh = NULL,
                covmat = cov(x), …)
```

I am curious to know does there any such usage exist in Julia? Looking for this. TIA.

Comment: You can solve such models with JuMP: https://jump.dev/Convex.jl/stable/examples/portfolio_optimization/portfolio_optimization/